# Can I update timestamp column to a desired Value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a column having timestamp column.

The table structure is something like this

```
[Time] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
```

When I insert in to this table using the following query

```
insert into test(id,name) values(1,'john')
```

Here I do not insert any value in Time column which is timestamp datatype but here some values are inserted automatically.

So I want to know If I can set my own seried value in this column like 3600 for 1 hour or 7200 for 2 hours so some time values

I tried like this

update test set Time=7200 but it showed me the following error

**Cannot update a timestamp column.**

I tried by giving a long value but still the same error

```
update test set Time=  '2005-05-13 07:15:31.123456789'
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the official documentation it is not possible, Unlike other DBMS it`s not used to store dates, But simply a 8bit value that is updated automatically.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Type **timestamp**  is simply a self computed binary field that you shouldn't and couldn't  update at the first place. If it is possible, use a custom added datetime field for your project.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible (at least it is in MySql) to create a regular field and give it a default value with Getdate() to have a field with something similar to the timestamp type.

Something similar to this,

ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT DF_YourTable DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR YourColumn

Of course your data field cannot be a timestamp type anymore.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot update a Timestamp. You can use something like:

[Time] [DATETIME] NOT NULL DEFAULT (GETDATE).

And you can modify the column whenever you want.